# Performing multiple updates in EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm currently using Entity Framework 4.3, Asp.Net 4.0, Sql Server 2008 Web.

I have method that loops through 10 to 20 loan providers. Each loan provider has a chance to bid for the loan - if they do the loop terminates - if not, they loop continues until all loan providers are consumed and a "no offers" message is returned.

I want to start logging this data - simply the lender and customer ID's. So for each customer who submits an application there maybe 1 to 20 inserts to perform. I can save these in a list and update them in 1 go.

As I'm using EF, I'm a little concerned about performance - I presume an insert will be done for each separate item added to the context.

Firstly - should I be worried about performance?
Secondly, are there any techniques I can use to make this process more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Entity Framework.  You must insert one row at a time in SQL, that's the way SQL works.  Each insert is a separate statement.  There is no way (outside of special bulk-insert methods, which would be pointless for 20 records) of doing it differently.

Now, yes, you can insert those 20 records in one request, which is what EF will do.

I don't understand you comment "As I'm using EF, I'm a little concerned about performance".  EF is no worse performing than anything else in this respect.  It's a simple 20 record insert, there's nothing special here or any complexity that could cause performance issues.

Comment: Thats cool - Sql is brand new and EF even newer. I had read that EF doesn't always create the most efficient SQL statements.

Comment: @dotnetnoob - EF is a tool, like any other tool you can use it to do things inefficiently.  You have to know sql in order to make sure you create efficient sql, either by hand or with a tool.  EF can't magically know what you mean when you tell it to do something inefficient, for all it knows you intended to do it that way.  The point is, EF doesn't absolve you from the need to know sql and to look at the performance of the sql that is used.